# Texmaker: Is there a way to compile main.tex eventhough some child-texfile is opened in the editor?

Tags: pdf, compilation, latex, shortcut, texmaker

The main.tex file in my project is the one to be opened in editor view in order to successfully compile the pdf-document. It has several child-files like e.g. content.tex where I write the actual thesis text.

Every time I want to compile the document in order to view the changes I have to change the editor-file to main.tex. Otherwise the process ends with errors.
I already tried the `Ctrl+0` base file setting, but it did not show any changes.

The LaTeX project is based on a template provided by my university and though has to stay untouched in regards of the project structure itself (why so ever...).

Comment: Hello, I think this is difficult to achieve. Personnaly I set every child file to be compilable on it's own, because (i) I can compile my chapter one by one when I'm working on them and (ii) it take less time to compile the chapter than my entire document when I want to check if one picture or table is well done. This is not an answer here because you need to add minor modifications to your template, and if you want to do more complicated stuff it can become really touchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do as I strived to. Don't know whether I'd just been too clumsy or if it relates to the problems I faced during the `\input{...}` integration, but if anyone wonders how to do so too:

It in fact has been the way I already tried - set the main-document to master-document.

Nevertheless I switched to use TexStudio meanwhile.
Thank you for your response @Gowachin